# Visual Studio 2015 does not install Android SDK tools for Api 19,21,23 etc for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am moving towards Xamarin for cross-platform application development. I already had VS2015 installed, I downloaded Xamarin tools(vstoolsforxamarin.exe) from their website and when I install them after a long wait VS says "setup completed with errors"and it does not download and install Android SDK for API 19,20,23, It always say:"Please check your internet connection and try again" and i am sure that my internet connection doesn't get disturbed during all this process. I have tried this 3 times now, tried by uninstalling VS2015, installing it again but got the same error. What is the problem that is causing this? I already have Android Studio installed, with its SDK manager. Any help would be appreciated, that to get Xamarin running in VS2015.

**EDIT:**
Solution:
I already had Android Studio and its SDK on my system, going to Tools>Options>Xamarin from Visual Studio and giving path of the Android SDK solved my problem. Read this answer on StackOverflow somewhere!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this issue is caused because Visual Studio is trying to download thrid-party libraries (Android SDK). You can fix this from Control-Panel

[image]

[Have a look at this post.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/780c0b11-41da-4935-9ae5-dadf38292b51/android-sdk-setup-api-not-installed?forum=vssetup)

Comment: Should i modify VS installation?

Comment: Well here's my solution:
I already had Android Studio and its SDK on my system, going to Tools>Options>Xamarin and giving path of the Android SDK solved my problem. Read this answer on StackOverflow somewhere!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have installed Java JDK, I had similar issue reported here
[Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Reports Internet Connectivity Issue while there is no issues with networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205792/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-reports-internet-connectivity-issue-while-there-is)

Answer (score 0):

As mwilson64 answered in response to [Android SDK Setup API not installed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/780c0b11-41da-4935-9ae5-dadf38292b51/android-sdk-setup-api-not-installed?forum=vssetup) (same as linked above on "Have a look at this post."), my steps to resolve:

1. Create file %USERPROFILE%.android\androidtool.cfg
2. Paste the following into new file (created in step 1):

   ```
   # Settings for Android Tool
   # Last updated: Wed May 19 17:09:27 UTC 2017
   http.proxyPort=8888
   sdkman.enable.previews=false
   http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
   sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false
   sdkman.show.update.only=true
   sdkman.force.http=false
   sdkman.use.dl.cache=true
   ```

Replace values in proxyPort and proxyHost with your company's proxy settings.