# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Reports Internet Connectivity Issue while there is no issues with networking

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, sdk

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 failing to install Android SDKs if Java JDK is not installed on the system but the error shown states there is internet connection issue.  Attempt to run SDK Manager executable does nothing and so does attempt to launch SDK Manager from Tools > Android menu.

However, attempt to install Android SDKs from Android Studio works flawlessly.

Why is Visual Studio reporting incorrect error suggesting there is an issue with internet connection even though there is no networking issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...btw, installing JDK fixed this for me but it is strange that VS complains about Network issue rather than missing JDK

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me [image]

I solved it by going to control panel->Programs and Features->Microsoft visual studio and the click on Change/Modify

Select the features tab then in common tools and software development kits.
There u can see the api's that u need to install via 3rd(party).

If u can't see those missing api levels restart and then try.
For me first i didnt get those api's later after restarting(i believe update and restart) i got those missing api's

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for Visual Studio Pro 2015. I resolved by installing JDK and restarting Windows. Then, I went to Control Panel -> Choose Visual Studio Professional -> Change -> Modify -> Select components and reinstall.